# program data structure: one big pointer or not?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

***Pseudo code:***

```
program calculator.h

struct calculation_information {
   int first_number;
   int second_number;
   int result;
}
struct division_errors{
   int divide_by_zero_error
}
struct window_information{
    int width;
    int height;
}
```

Do I provide pointers to every single data structure and keep em separated?
so a function call would look like:

```
divide(2,3, pointer_to_division_error, pointer_to_calculation_information)
```

Or do I include a general overall struct in the .h file:

```
struct program_data{
    calculation_information *calculation_information_pointer;
    division_errors *division_errors_pointer;
    window_information *window_information_pointer;
}
```

and provide one pointer to all the information of the program?
so a function call would look like:

```
divide(2,3, pointer_to_program_data)
```

Comment: Lol this is for you to decide.

Comment: This is more of a design choice than a question of what is *correct*, personally I would go with the second option.